# message queue (systemvipc) removed in OpenSUSE Leap 15.5 while working in SLES15 SP3 or under root user

Tags: c, linux, opensuse, suse, sysv-ipc

I have a IPC mechanism auto removal issue happening on OpenSUSE Leap 15.5 Beta but not happening on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server SP3.

A simple scenario is this executable put in a service script:

```
# > cat ipc.c
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main()
{
  int msqid;
  key_t  msgqKey = ftok("/home/",0);

  msqid = msgget(msgqKey, IPC_CREAT | 0766);
  return 0;
}
# >
```

and that executable runs under a certain user (non root). After I restart that service I can see for less than 10 seconds via `ipcs -q` that new message queue but then it dissapears.

If in the startup script I have this the message queue gets removed (automatically):

```
su my_user -c "exec /my/above/executable"
```

If in the startup script I have this the message queue is preserved:

```
exec /my/above/executable
```

The RemoveIPC and DynamicUser that I've found about seem to be ok according to the [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.exec.5.html).

```
# systemctl show systemd-logind --property=DynamicUser --property=RemoveIPC
DynamicUser=no
RemoveIPC=no
#
```

Any pointers or a way to read the docs more carefully is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the reponsible is systemd-logind and, most likely,

```
# systemctl show systemd-logind --property=DynamicUser --property=RemoveIPC
DynamicUser=no
RemoveIPC=no
#
```

is not executed in the proper context.

Putting explicitly in the config file this setting makes everything work fine:

```
Assistant-linux:/home/engr # cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf | grep -v ^#

[Login]
RemoveIPC=no
Assistant-linux:/home/engr #
```

Looks like the systemd people have their own opinion related to legacy code, at least this is my impression: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2039